# Fonts not rendering on wordpress site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have created a pure html website which has a blog section which is developed in WordPress. I have used "PostGrid" plugin for showing a grid like structure and used posts section in WordPress that allows adding post on that blog section.

The issue that i'm facing is :
[image]

In above image fonts are rendered properly, but not on 2nd page.

[image]

On the following url `http://localhost/wordpress/home/`, I have all my blogs. On this page, I can add upto six posts, If i add more blogs, then it gets added to the next page as there is a built-in pagination support provided by WordPress.

The blogs which i've added on above URL are proper with custom fonts but if i add more posts/blogs it goes to next page that is : `http://localhost/wordpress/home/page/2/`, Here the font doesn't get rendered and shows error in console.

> GET http://localhost/wordpress/home/page/fonts/Gilroy-Semibold.ttf
>   net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found).

the path for my fonts is same for the post's home page as well as for page 2, but on page 2 it is not rendering.

I have tried all the solutions, by adding css on console, also i changed the css from Simple CSS from WordPress but it is not loading.

Can anyone help me for this issue, i will share the code.

I'm using below CSS in Simple CSS in WordPress & it is same for Both blog page.

```
@font-face {
    font-family:gilroylight;
    src: url("../fonts/Gilroy-Light.ttf");

  }
@font-face {
    font-family:gilroysemibold;
    src: url("../fonts/Gilroy-Semibold.ttf");
  }
@font-face {
    font-family:keepcalm;
    src: url("../fonts/KEEPCALM-MEDIUM_0.TTF");
}
```

Comment: I'm new to wordpress, i have no idea what code shoud i share. so i have added images of my web page.

Comment: How are you adding the fonts? The most common method for loading locally hosted fonts will be through a font-face declaration in the theme stylesheet, although there are other possibilities (as ever) - so /wp-content/themes/yourtheme/assets/fonts/fontfile.ext might be one typical file location.

Comment: I have added fonts in Simple CSS  in wordpress. Its working for post home page but not on 2nd page.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/main-stylesheet-style-css/ Best/recommended practice is to create a child theme for making theme modifications.https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ A tool like Simple CSS is in my opinion outdated and not the preferred location for font declatations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a path issue for the font file, please check it in the console window. and change your path/url in your style/css.

```
/* If css and fonts are in same folder*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url('CustomFont.ttf');
}

/* If fonts is outside of your css folder*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url('../CustomFont.ttf');
}

/* Absolute static path of fonts file*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url('file:///C:/Users/Administrator/fonts/CustomFont.ttf');
}

/* Url path of fonts file*/
@font-face {
    font-family: "CustomFont";
    src: url('http://localhost/wordpress/Your-font-folder-path/CustomFont.ttf');
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, could please tell me  how to add fonts in in wordpress.ie URL fonts.

Comment: try to add font-face style into your css file. and use this css file to all pages.

Answer (score 0):

In your style CSS : Replace your path src and font family according

```
@font-face {
  font-family: Roboto;
  src: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyseventeen-child/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf);
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, could you please tell me how can i add these fonts in my wordpress site